# How can I see Deno transpiled javascript when writing in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I'm learning Typescript using Deno and wanted do see javaScript result.
Is there some command line I didn't see on docs?

ps.: I Know there's no compiling step using Deno, but at some point it must have a Javascript code so V8 engine can run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transpiled code will be stored in

```
$DENO_DIR/gen
```

`$DENO_DIR` varies depending on the OS

- On Linux/Redox:  `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno`  or  `$HOME/.cache/deno`
- On Windows:  `%LOCALAPPDATA%/deno`  (`%LOCALAPPDATA% = FOLDERID_LocalAppData`)
- On macOS:  `$HOME/Library/Caches/deno`  If something fails, it falls back to  `$HOME/.deno`

---

You can check the location doing:

```
deno info
```

Which will output:

```
DENO_DIR location: "/home/user/.cache/deno"
Remote modules cache: "/home/user/.cache/deno/deps"
TypeScript compiler cache: "/home/user/.cache/deno/gen"
```

If you do the following `import`:

```
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/http/server.ts'
```

You'll see the transpiled JavaScript code in:

```
$DENO_DIR/gen/https/deno.land/std@v0.51.0/http
```

Doing:

```
ls $DENO_DIR/gen/https/deno.land/std@v0.51.0/http
```

You'll see:

```
http_status.ts.js
http_status.ts.js.map
http_status.ts.meta
_io.ts.js
_io.ts.js.map
_io.ts.meta
server.ts.js
server.ts.js.map
server.ts.meta
```